# Duplicated sources C, linux

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse to edit my sources. I noticed that in a project directory duplicates of my recently edited source files appeared, which begin with *.# and end with number. For example for the source1.c there is a duplicate *.#source1.c1.1.1. As I understand it's some project cache or something. Can anyone tell me what are those files for and how to prohibit their creation?

Comment: Maybe something related to some CVS? Maybe a temporary merge file?

Comment: I'm totally guessing. I supposed that are file managed by tools as [Git](https://git-scm.com/), [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/). [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)

Comment: Probably you are right, thanx.